# После вызова функции через setInterval() исчезает все

Tags: javascript, html, таймер

Имеется функция которая пишет строчку (**document.write**).
Она вызывается через **setInterval()**.
Почему **setInterval** удаляет все HTML элементы вместо того чтобы добавлять текст к ним?

```js
var seconds = 1;

function repeatWrite(){
  document.write(seconds + " seconds left" + "<br>");
  seconds++
}

setInterval(repeatWrite, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Появляющийся текст!</h1>
<p>Каждую секунду ниже должен появляться текст</p>
<p>Но почему все эти HTML элементы исчезают?</p>
```

Comment: Потому что надо хоть немного изучить язык, прежде, чем на нём писать. `document.write` заменяет содержимое документа.

Comment: Не используйте document.write в 2017 году, пожалуйста

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749856/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методы `document.write` и `document.writeln` работают только пока HTML-страница находится в процессе загрузки. Если страница загружена, то `document.write()` уже не может ничего добавить на страницу

Технически, вызвать `document.write` можно в любое время, однако, когда HTML загрузился, и браузер полностью построил DOM, документ становится «закрытым». Попытка дописать что-то в закрытый документ открывает его заново. При этом все текущее содержимое удаляется.

Из-за этой особенности `document.write` для загруженных документов не используют. Вместо этого используйте `innerHTML`

```js
var seconds = 1;

function repeatWrite(){
  document.getElementById('add').innerHTML += (seconds + " seconds left" + "<br>");
  seconds++
}

setInterval(repeatWrite, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Появляющийся текст!</h1>
<p>Каждую секунду ниже должен появляться текст</p>
<p>Но почему все эти HTML элементы исчезают?</p>
<p id="add"></p>
```

[Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write)

Comment: Я в процессе изучения JS, но с этой проблемой столкнулся только когда вызвал функцию с document.write через setInterval. До этого document.write добавлял текст к HTML, и таких проблем не было. Вот пример, который только что сделал: https://code.sololearn.com/WJA9SV1jLoac/#js

Comment: @Rumata Читайте еще раз, я все объяснил. Если не понятно - читайте в источнике, там подробнее.

Comment: Хотя если заключить document.write в функцию window.onload снова все сотрется. То есть дело в том подгружается ли JS после или до HTML?  снова странно - ведь я подключил внешний js файл в конце body, а значит должно получиться так  же как с window.onload

Comment: Метод `document.write()` работает только пока HTML-страница находится в процессе загрузки. Если страница загружена (`onload`), то `document.write()` уже не может ничего добавить на страницу

Comment: Поэтому страница снова "открывается", чтобы document.write сработал, и все созданное до него стирается, верно?

Comment: @Rumata Типа того

Comment: теперь понимаю, спасибо большое за подробное объяснение! НО почему этого не происходит когда внешний js скрипт подключается в самом низу body. Разве это не эквивалентно onload (HTML уже построен)?

Comment: Технически, это не конец документа, ведь `<html>` не закрыт

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

[document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) пишет в поток документа, первый же вызов очищает весь DOM(переоткрывает документ), это нормальное поведение.

Используйте другие методы.

```js
var seconds = 1;

function repeatWrite(){
  document.body.innerHTML += ("<br/>"+seconds + " seconds left");
  seconds++
}

setInterval(repeatWrite, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Появляющийся текст!</h1>
<p>Каждую секунду ниже должен появляться текст</p>
<p>Но почему все эти HTML элементы исчезают?</p>
```

Comment: Я в процессе изучения JS, но с этой проблемой столкнулся только когда вызвал функцию с document.write через setInterval. До этого document.write добавлял текст к HTML, и таких проблем не было. Вот пример, который только что сделал: code.sololearn.com/WJA9SV1jLoac/#js

Comment: В вашем примере `document.write` вызывается до формирования DOM

Comment: Спасибо большое!  Я еще изучаю JS, многое пока не вполне понятно)

Comment: Строго говоря, `document` - не является частью js) Это часть [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference)